# Mysql PDO return double result on select

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I trying to make a login form which validate the user/pass from database with PHP, is not something wrong but my code output double result, why? Is not something which I can't handle but why it returns double result?

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE username = '$username'");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($row)
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [password] => 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
            [0] => 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
        )

)
```

Why 2 times?

Comment: Try `->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` if you want the keyword.

Comment: Separate note, that is not how prepared statements are meant to be used and is open to SQL injections. `WHERE username = ?`,  `$stmt->execute(array($username))`

Comment: @DanielH. worked.